# Is there a way to generate SHA256 or similar in nodejs of big files?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to generate the sha256 of a huge buffer (2.5G), sadly the hash.update throws already an error (ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE)

```
RangeError: data is too long
    at Hash.update (node:internal/crypto/hash:113:22)
```

from my understanding I cannot do multiple updates on the createHash('sha256').
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#hashupdatedata-inputencoding

is there another way to handle big buffers except writing them to disk and then calling ie sha256sum and processing the output?

Simple example to reproduce:

```js
const {createHash} = require("crypto")

const hash = createHash('sha256')

const data = new Buffer.alloc(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 3, 1)

hash.update(data)

console.log(hash.digest('hex'))
```

Comment: How do you come that understanding? The docs explicitly say otherwise "*This can be called many times with new data as it is streamed.*" So split your buffer in smaller chunks and call update with the smaller chunks (in the correct order!). Once you are finished call `digest` Even the example in the docs calls `update` multiple times, ie the last digest outputted will be the digest of `onetwothree` ...

Comment: I honestly missed the second paragraph. Will try that now

Comment: The only limitation is, you cannot call `update` anymore once you called `digest`.

Comment: ok, do you know by chance the limit of the chunk size that can be passed to update?

Comment: No, sorry. But I guess a a few 100MB will probably be ok. But probably the limit is some `2^x`  maybe even 2GB

Answer (score 1):

The [`Hash` class](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/crypto.html#class-hash) extends `stream.Transform` and the documentation shows how to use `Hash` and piped streams to read data from a file, pass it through the `Hash` transformer and write the outcome (the hash) in another file:

```js
import { createReadStream } from 'node:fs';
import { stdout } from 'node:process';
const { createHash } = await import('node:crypto');

const hash = createHash('sha256');

const input = createReadStream('test.js');
input.pipe(hash).setEncoding('hex').pipe(stdout);
```

This example shows the power of Node.js streams and can be used to produce a function that fulfills your needs:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const stream = require('stream/promises');

async function computeHash(filepath) {
  const input = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
  const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
  
  // Connect the output of the `input` stream to the input of `hash`
  // and let Node.js do the streaming
  await stream.pipeline(input, hash);

  return hash.digest('hex');
}
```

Usage:

```js
const hash = await computeHash('/path-to-file');
```

Answer (score 0):

thx @derpirscher!

hash.update can be called as often as needed, the hashing itself will end with the call to digest()

To now handle bigger buffers it is easiest to split the buffer into smaller chunks and pass them into the hash.

```js
const {createHash} = require("crypto")

const hash = createHash('sha256')
const data = new Buffer.alloc(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 3, 1)

const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024
const chunks = Math.ceil(data.length / chunkSize)

for (let i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
  hash.update(data.subarray(i * chunkSize, (i+1) * chunkSize))
}

console.log(hash.digest('hex'))
```